# Select an specific text fragment in a HTML and add bold font with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to add a bold font in an specific text fragment in a HTML. Where it says (10,90% TAE)* in the image.

[image]

The problem is that I have to inject it with Adobe target using javascript and this whole text numbers changes dynamically with javascript.

The original code is:

```
<p class="small clr-gray summary-interest" ing-unmask=""><span class="clr-black">10,39 % TIN</span> (10,90 % TAE)*</p>
```

And I want to bold (10,90% TAE)* like this with javascript:

```
<p class="small clr-gray summary-interest" ing-unmask=""><span class="clr-black">10,39 % TIN</span> <b>(10,90 % TAE)*<b></p>
```

I tried using the split method and select the part I want to bold but I dont know how to add it right:

"TIN":

```
var startN = document.querySelector("#summary-region > div > div > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2) > p.small.clr-gray.summary-interest").innerHTML.split(" ")[3];
```

"TAE)*":

```
var finishN = document.querySelector("#summary-region > div > div > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2) > p.small.clr-gray.summary-interest").innerHTML.split(" ")[6];
```

The whole text is:

```
textocompleto = document.querySelector("#summary-region > div > div > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2) > p.small.clr-gray.summary-interest");
```

I guess I have to use the `.innerHTML` but I dont know how to use it right. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing this with JavaScript would look something like this:

```js
const node = document.querySelector('p.summary-interest');
const span = document.querySelector('p.summary-interest span');
const text = node.childNodes[1].textContent;
newHTML = `${span.innerHTML}<b>${text}</b>`;
node.innerHTML = newHTML;
```

```html
<p class="small clr-gray summary-interest" ing-unmask=""><span class="clr-black">10,39 % TIN</span> (10,90 % TAE)*</p>
```

Comment: This works perfect!!!!! :O thank you so much! I am new developer learning!

Comment: You are very welcome. Please accept this answer if you are so inclined.

Comment: How can I accept the answer? im new with stackoverflow! thank you!

Comment: I meant this: Acceptance is indicated by a colored checkmark next to the answer that has been accepted by the original author of the question. Just just click the check mark.